# Redhat openshift cluster creation error on azure

Tags: deployment, openshift, cluster-computing, redhat

I am trying to create a redhat openshift cluster . Getting an error shown below while creating the cluster
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 8ec2b1a1-6f67-4800-a093-4db8097bdd87. OpenShift Managed Cluster validation failed with error: [invalid properties.fqdn "osab09538423093495092fe.WestUS.cloudapp.azure.com"]

Comment: Getting this error

Comment: Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 822f1532-f03a-4ccc-83d5-603497dfebfe. Code="InvalidTemplateDeployment" Message="The template deployment 'b800fe18-dddb-4299-8bb0-f5cc60734dc1' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '20d23cb4-0ddc-4305-962a-53f5e0ebea82'. See inner errors for details." Details=[{"code":"QuotaExceeded","message":"Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved Total Regional Cores quota.